# Target confusion at compile time

Tags: build-process, xcode4.5, target

I am working on a project, in xCode 4.5.2 with 2 targets T1 and T2.

When I want to build T1, I get error messages about one file only belonging to T2.

Obviously, even though I think the file belongs to T2, the compiler thinks differently.
Where do I need to check? As far as I can see, I have done the necessary for the file to be inside T2 and not inside T1.
But I must be forgetting something. Any idea?

Thanks for any useful tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the "target membership" for the file... click on the file in your project and then look at the "File Inspector" along the right side of your Xcode project window:

[image: Make sure Target Membership is selected for your .m file]

In this case, I've just looked up the target membership for the UIKit.framework, but in your case  you should see which target membership the file in question belongs to.

Comment: The thing is I already did that from the beginning and everything looks all right. There must be something more I am missing or doing wrong. I have no experience with handling multitargets on iOS.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the error message in detail and also the membership settings of the file in question (i.e. your project window)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the question. There is no error message any more. But when I compile a given target it is taking the wrong file when importing. It looks simple, but for some reason I am not getting the result I expect for my settings.

Comment: More precisely it is always taking the same DF_List.h file, whatever target I build.

Comment: The more I read on the net about targets handling, the more I feel I am not getting it right from start.
I can see statements like: "there's no sense in target membership for header files".

In that case what do I do if I need to have target T1 to import this X.h and target T2 to import that different X.h?

Comment: Yes, you should never have .h files as target members (since they're likely to be included and copied into your application package... oops!).  When I first looked at your question, I was assuming you were talking about .m files or frameworks. Can you set conditionals in each of your targets PCH files and then modify your .h files to work with the correct conditional for the target you want to load?